# Encrypt file in python with aes

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I want to encrypt and decrypt a file (any type of file) using aes 128 in cbc mode in python.

I am quite new to cryptography and i have tried some tutorials but all work only on texts, and i need it for files.

Could anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to AES encrypt/decrypt files using Python/PyCrypto in an OpenSSL-compatible way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761458/how-to-aes-encrypt-decrypt-files-using-python-pycrypto-in-an-openssl-compatible)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick Google search guided me to the [Crypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) package. It comes with the iPython that I am using, but the installation should be trivial anyway.

I just [repost](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) the example here for your information.

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
>>> message = "The answer is no"
>>> ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
>>> ciphertext
'\xd6\x83\x8dd!VT\x92\xaa`A\x05\xe0\x9b\x8b\xf1'
>>> obj2 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
>>> obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
'The answer is no'
```

[Here](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/toc-Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html) is the documentation of AES.

If you try to encrypt file, you can either use the openSSL or a Python solution using Crypto contributed by Thijs. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761458/how-to-aes-encrypt-decrypt-files-using-python-pycrypto-in-an-openssl-compatible) for more information.

Comment: Be aware that this library has been abandoned for years.