# AES encryption of file using Pycrypto

Tags: android, python, encryption, pycrypto

I am trying to find the correct way to encrypt files using Pycrypto. Every method I have found online doesn't seem to decrypt in Android or online at sites like http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/

Here is the Python code I have tried:

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def pad(s):
    return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

def encrypt(message, key, iv):
    message = pad(message)
    #iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    print iv
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)

def decrypt(ciphertext, key, iv):
    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:])
    return plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")

def encrypt_file(file_name, key, iv):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        plaintext = fo.read()
    enc = encrypt(plaintext, key, iv)
    with open(file_name + ".enc", 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(enc)

def decrypt_file(file_name, key, iv):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
        ciphertext = fo.read()
    dec = decrypt(ciphertext, key, iv)
    with open(file_name[:-1], 'wb') as fo:
        fo.write(dec)


#key = b'\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x94\x02)j\xdf\xcb\xc4\x94\x9d(\x9e[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\xd5\x18'
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase

key = (''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(16)))
print key
iv = (''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(16)))
#iv = hex(iv)
print iv
encrypt_file('Grass.jpg', key, iv)
decrypt_file('Grass.jpg.enc', key, iv)
```

Here is the Android code I am using to decrypt (I have tried Nopadding and PKCS5Padding)

```java
package com.jgarin.encryptingtestapp;

import android.util.Base64;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

   /*****************************************************************
    * CrossPlatform CryptLib
    * 
    * <p>
    * This cross platform CryptLib uses AES 256 for encryption. This library can
    * be used for encryptoion and de-cryption of string on iOS, Android and Windows
    * platform.<br/>
    * Features: <br/>
    * 1. 256 bit AES encryption
    * 2. Random IV generation. 
    * 3. Provision for SHA256 hashing of key. 
    * </p>
    * 
    * @since 1.0
    * @author navneet
    *****************************************************************/

public class CryptLib {

   /**
    * Encryption mode enumeration
    */
   private enum EncryptMode {
      ENCRYPT, DECRYPT;
   }

   // cipher to be used for encryption and decryption
   Cipher cipher;

   // encryption key and initialization vector
   byte[] key, iv;

   public CryptLib() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
      // initialize the cipher with transformation AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
      cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
//    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
      key = new byte[16]; //256 bit key space
      iv = new byte[16]; //128 bit IV
   }

   /**
    * Note: This function is no longer used. 
    * This function generates md5 hash of the input string
    * @param inputString
    * @return md5 hash of the input string
    */
   public static final String md5(final String inputString) {
       final String MD5 = "MD5";
       try {
           // Create MD5 Hash
           MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                   .getInstance(MD5);
           digest.update(inputString.getBytes());
           byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

           // Create Hex String
           StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
           for (byte aMessageDigest : messageDigest) {
               String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & aMessageDigest);
               while (h.length() < 2)
                   h = "0" + h;
               hexString.append(h);
           }
           return hexString.toString();

       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return "";
   }

   /**
    * 
    * @param inputData
    *            Text to be encrypted or decrypted
    * @param _encryptionKey
    *            Encryption key to used for encryption / decryption
    * @param _mode
    *            specify the mode encryption / decryption
    * @param _initVector
    *           Initialization vector
    * @return encrypted or decrypted string based on the mode
    * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    * @throws InvalidKeyException
    * @throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
    * @throws BadPaddingException
    */
      private byte[] encryptDecrypt(byte[] inputData, String _encryptionKey,
         EncryptMode _mode, String _initVector) throws UnsupportedEncodingException,
         InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
         IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
      byte[] _out = new byte[0];// output string

      int len = _encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8").length; // length of the key    provided

      if (_encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8").length > key.length)
         len = key.length;

      int ivlen = _initVector.getBytes("UTF-8").length;

      if(_initVector.getBytes("UTF-8").length > iv.length)
         ivlen = iv.length;

      System.arraycopy(_encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, key, 0, len);
      System.arraycopy(_initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, iv, 0, ivlen);
      //KeyGenerator _keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
      //_keyGen.init(128);

      SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"); // Create a new SecretKeySpec
                           // for the
                           // specified key
                           // data and
                           // algorithm
                           // name.

      IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv); // Create a new
                        // IvParameterSpec
                        // instance with the
                        // bytes from the
                        // specified buffer
                        // iv used as
                        // initialization
                        // vector.

      // encryption
      if (_mode.equals(EncryptMode.ENCRYPT)) {
         // Potentially insecure random numbers on Android 4.3 and older.
         // Read
         // https://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/some-securerandom-thoughts.html
         // for more info.
         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);// Initialize this cipher instance
         _out = cipher.doFinal(inputData); // Finish
                              // multi-part
                              // transformation
                              // (encryption)
      }

      // decryption
      if (_mode.equals(EncryptMode.DECRYPT)) {
         cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);// Initialize this cipher instance

         _out = cipher.doFinal(inputData); // Finish
                           // multi-part
                           // transformation
                           // (decryption)
      }
      System.out.println(_out);
      return _out; // return encrypted/decrypted string
   }

   /***
    * This function computes the SHA256 hash of input string
    * @param text input text whose SHA256 hash has to be computed
    * @param length length of the text to be returned
    * @return returns SHA256 hash of input text 
    * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    */
   public static String SHA256 (String text, int length) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

       String resultStr;
      MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

       md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
       byte[] digest = md.digest();

       StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
       for (byte b : digest) {
           result.append(String.format("%02x", b)); //convert to hex
       }
       //return result.toString();

       if(length > result.toString().length())
       {
          resultStr = result.toString();
       }
       else 
       {
          resultStr = result.toString().substring(0, length);
       }

       return resultStr;

   }

   /***
    * This function encrypts the plain text to cipher text using the key
    * provided. You'll have to use the same key for decryption
    * 
    * @param _plainText
    *            Plain text to be encrypted
    * @param _key
    *            Encryption Key. You'll have to use the same key for decryption
    * @param _iv
    *         initialization Vector
    * @return returns encrypted (cipher) text
    * @throws InvalidKeyException
    * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    * @throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
    * @throws BadPaddingException
    */

   public String encrypt(String _plainText, String _key, String _iv)
         throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException,
         InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
         BadPaddingException {

        byte[] bytes = encryptDecrypt(_plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"), _key, EncryptMode.ENCRYPT, _iv);
        String result = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT); // ciphertext
        return result;
   }

   public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, String _key, String _iv)
         throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException,
         InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
         BadPaddingException {
      return encryptDecrypt(data, _key, EncryptMode.ENCRYPT, _iv);
   }

   /***
    * This funtion decrypts the encrypted text to plain text using the key
    * provided. You'll have to use the same key which you used during
    * encryprtion
    * 
    * @param data
    *            Encrypted/Cipher text to be decrypted
    * @param _key
    *            Encryption key which you used during encryption
    * @param _iv
    *         initialization Vector
    * @return encrypted value
    * @throws InvalidKeyException
    * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    * @throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
    * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
    * @throws BadPaddingException
    */
   public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data, String _key, String _iv)
         throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException,
         InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
         BadPaddingException {
      return encryptDecrypt(data, _key, EncryptMode.DECRYPT, _iv);
   }

   public String decrypt(String inputString, String _key, String _iv)
         throws InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException,
         InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
         BadPaddingException {
        byte[] decryptedVal = encryptDecrypt(Base64.decode(inputString, Base64.DEFAULT), _key, EncryptMode.DECRYPT, _iv);
        String result = new String(decryptedVal, "UTF-8");
        return result;
   }

   /**
   * this function generates random string for given length
   * @param length
   *           Desired length
   * * @return 
   */
   public static String generateRandomIV(int length)
   {
      SecureRandom ranGen = new SecureRandom();
      byte[] aesKey = new byte[16];
      ranGen.nextBytes(aesKey);
      StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
       for (byte b : aesKey) {
           result.append(String.format("%02x", b)); //convert to hex
       }
       if(length> result.toString().length())
       {
          return result.toString();
       }
       else
       {
          return result.toString().substring(0, length);
       }
   }
}
```

Any help with what I am doing wrong will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20457519/4014959 FWIW, I've tested that code against openssl and it works correctly.

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to AES encrypt/decrypt files using Python/PyCrypto in an OpenSSL-compatible way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761458/how-to-aes-encrypt-decrypt-files-using-python-pycrypto-in-an-openssl-compatible)