# openssl password decryption using Python

Tags: php, python, encryption, openssl, encryption-symmetric

I'm using the following PHP code to encrypt a password and then saving it into a database, I need to be able to decrypt it using Python.

I am successful in decrypting it using PHP but unable to find away
of doing so using Python(I'm using version 2.7.9 if it matters)..

```
$mypass = "somepassword"
$encryptionMethod = "AES-256-CBC";  
$secretHash = "25c6c78835b7479b151f2136cd888777";

$encpass = openssl_encrypt($mypass, $encryptionMethod, $secretHash);
```

I have no issues opening and reading from the DB, my only problem is the decryption portion.
Any suggestions would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? [let me give you a point in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761458/how-to-aes-encrypt-decrypt-files-using-python-pycrypto-in-an-openssl-compatible)

Comment: Why would one want to do this? Encrypting a password like that is like building a castle and then hiring a little boy to scare of those who enter through the drawbridge one is convinced to leave open at the time of an attack...

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/16761458/535275

Comment: You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution... The code below seems to be working, I'm sure there is a more efficent way of doing that but for now it's doing what I need it to do... Hoping this will help someone else in the future. Please keep in mind it's not a secure way to protect data!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os
def decryption(encryptedString):
    PADDING = '{'
    DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)
    #Key is FROM the printout of 'secret' in encryption
    #below is the encryption.
    encryption = encryptedString
    key = "25c6c78835b7479b151f2136cd888777"
    cipher = AES.new(key)
    decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encryption)
    #print decoded
    return decoded

enc_message = "p7OslgBJ5RlTBDG4ZD8HEA"  # in my case it will be the data from the database
enc_message = enc_message + "=="
data = decryption(enc_message)
data = data.rstrip()
print data
```