# 256 AES encryption in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, aes

I tried to make a program that will encrypt some string with 256 AES. But I'm not able to decrypt it.

Here is the code

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import os, base64

block_size = 32

def pad(s):
        return s + "\0" * (block_size - len(s) % block_size)

key = os.urandom(block_size)
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
enc = cipher.encrypt(pad('Hello World'))

print 'Encrypted', enc

iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
key = os.urandom(block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
dec = cipher.decrypt(enc[block_size:])
dec_rstrip = dec.rstrip("\0")

print 'Decrypted', dec_rstrip
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decrypt OpenSSL AES-encrypted files in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761458/how-to-decrypt-openssl-aes-encrypted-files-in-python)

Comment: "Please write a decryption tool for this encryption code" is not a reasonably-scoped question, nor one likely  to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are using a different random key for encryption and decryption, it must be the same.
2. The decryption iv is never initialized, it needs to one the same for encryption and decryption..