# Is there a way decrypt OpenSSL AES-encrypted files in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, openssl, aes

I encrypted some files using openssl aes-256-cbc command in terminal

`openssl aes-256-cbc -in filename.txt -out filename.enc -k password`

Unfortunately I am unable to decrypt those files using Python 3.x

I tried using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16761459/10565173), but TypeError occurs

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

def derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, iv_length):
    d = d_i = ''
    while len(d) < key_length + iv_length:
        d_i = md5(d_i + password + salt).digest()
        d += d_i
    return d[:key_length], d[key_length:key_length+iv_length]

def decrypt(in_file, out_file, password, key_length=32):
    bs = AES.block_size
    salt = in_file.read(bs)[len('Salted__'):]
    key, iv = derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, bs)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    next_chunk = ''
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        chunk, next_chunk = next_chunk, cipher.decrypt(in_file.read(1024 * bs))
        if len(next_chunk) == 0:
            padding_length = ord(chunk[-1])
            chunk = chunk[:-padding_length]
            finished = True
        out_file.write(chunk)
```

So, could python decrypt openssl aes-encrypted files?

Comment: The post you linked has a Python 3 answer farther down

Comment: Also tried using this code and it doesn't work at all

Comment: `TypeError` *where*? What have you tried to get rid of it?

Comment: I simply get TypeError by running code from the answer, `d_i = md5(d_i + password + salt).digest()
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
`

Comment: You mean, you get this error when you use a library function which starts with "Deprecated since version 2.5: Use the hashlib module instead."? Gosh.

Comment: Even after updating my code and using hashlib module, the code simply runs into the same error