# How to decrypt openssl encrypted file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, encryption, pyopenssl

I have a file which was encrypted using Linux command line tool **openssl**.
eg: openssl smime -encrypt -binary -aes-256-cbc -in 400000005f16bec1298bbc0c0079371de75e -out 400000005f16bec1298bbc0c0079371de75e_enc -outform DER **/usr/local/etc/key.pem**

How to decrypt this file in Python? Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit-1:**
I have /usr/local/etc/key.pem is available with me, it has private key and certificate details and I must use this pem file to decrypt/encrypt the files in Python

**Edit-2:**
Used the C functionality which I have to encrypt/decrypt the file. Invoking the C binary from Python code worked for me.

Comment: One way is to invoke openssl inside python.

Comment: In python, I can able to get the files decrypted using os.popen(). But I am looking for programmatic way to decrypt them using Python libraries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761458/how-to-decrypt-openssl-aes-encrypted-files-in-python

Comment: Thank you Philippe, I looked into the post you have shared, here they are not reading/generating the password/key from "pem file". In my case I have the pem file and I should fetch a key from it and then continue to decrypt the file