# Decrypt AES-256-CBC with PBKDF2 from OpenSSL in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, openssl, pbkdf2

I need to decrypt a string that was encrypted with OpenSSL as following:

```
openssl rand -out secret.key -hex 192
openssl aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -in file_to_encrypt -out encrypted_file -pass file:secret.key
```

And i can't get it to work in C#

```
  public void OnStartup()
  {
    using var rsa = RSA.Create();
    var privateKeyContent = File.ReadAllText("/cert/customer.pem");
    rsa.ImportFromPem(privateKeyContent);
    var encryptedSecret = File.ReadAllBytes("license/secret.key.enc");
    var decrypted = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedSecret, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
    _logger.LogInformation(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted));
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("license/license.json.enc");
    var license = DecryptAesCbc(bytes, decrypted);
    _logger.LogInformation(license);
  }

  public string DecryptAesCbc(byte[] cipheredData, byte[] passphrase)
  {
    string decrypted = null;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(cipheredData))
    {
      // Get salt
      var salt = new byte[8];
      ms.Seek(8, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      ms.Read(salt, 0, 8);
      _logger.LogInformation("Salt: {Salt}", string.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(salt, x => x.ToString("X2"))));

      // Derive key and IV
      var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passphrase, salt, 10000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
      byte[] key = pbkdf2.GetBytes(32);
      byte[] iv = pbkdf2.GetBytes(16);
      _logger.LogInformation("Key: {Key}", string.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(key, x => x.ToString("X2"))));
      _logger.LogInformation("IV: {IV}", string.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(iv, x => x.ToString("X2"))));

      using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
      aes.KeySize = 256;
      aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
      aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
      aes.Key = key;
      aes.IV = iv;

      // Decrypt
      ICryptoTransform decipher = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
                using var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decipher, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
      using var sr = new StreamReader(cs, Encoding.UTF8);
      decrypted = sr.ReadToEnd();
      }
      return decrypted;
    }
```

With this code i receive an exception at `decrypted = sr.ReadToEnd()` `Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.`

The secret is encrypted via RSA and decrypted, the result is the same as the the decrypted file, so this should be working.

Im very thankful for help

Comment: Please post your most recent C# code and describe the problem.

Comment: I updated my question with my c# code

Comment: The code seems to be OK. I can't reproduce the problem either. Maybe the bug is in the data import (key and ciphertext), which you did not post.

Comment: Note that because of the `-hex` option, the 192 byte password is stored in hex encoded form and is also used in hex encoded form when encrypting. Therefore, no hex decoding may be performed during decryption.

Comment: Are you aware that the password (and not a key) is read during encryption from _secret.key_? From that password a 256 bits key is then generated using PBKDF2. Therefore the `line aes.KeySize = 192` is wrong (which btw specifies the key size in bits and not bytes), but doesn't cause a problem, since the true key is set after this line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes i have noticed that the keysize should be 256.

Comment: I will try to generate the secret.key without the hex option and check if that changes anything

Comment: If you still have trouble, you should post the C# code for importing passphrase and data.

Comment: So now i generate the secret with base64. It doesnt work either. I have noticed yesterday that i extract the salt correct, but the key and iv isn't the same as openssl prints with the -p option. I will update the post with the code that loads the data

Comment: Base64 encoding will probably cause the same issue here, rather try to store the password in binary. The different key/IV indeed speaks for different passwords and a possible problem during import.

Comment: What .NET version do you use?

Comment: dotnet version 5.0.300

Comment: I now have generated the secret as bytes and can verify that the decrypting with RSA results in the same byte array as the non encrypted secret generated by openssl

Comment: I.e. `decrypted` now corresponds to the _binary_ data of `secret.key`? Then, compare key and IV from openssl and the C# code.

Comment: Yes correct. I already compared and they are different. The salt is correct but Key and IV are different

Comment: Can you post test data? Create via openssl a short password (e.g. 5 bytes) in binary (without hex and base64) and import it on C# side directly without RSA encryption/decryption. Encrypt a short plaintext with openssl. Read the password with a hex editor and post it hex encoded, also plaintext and openssl ciphertext.

Comment: Also note that you must not encode arbitrary binary data with UTF8 (as you do when logging), because that corrupts the data. But this seems to happen only when logging and is therefore not critical.

Comment: Password: 6A B2 F8 51 25  


Plaintext: "any text" (without quotes)  


Cipher: 53616C7465645F5F905ECB3B440DF58693F4FEA915513820C89457A97D9CE0A3

Comment: Can be decrypted on my machine with C# without any problems. Can you run the openssl statement with -P -S 905ECB3B440DF586 and post key and IV? Use a capital -P so that only the data is output, but no encryption is performed.

Comment: key=FBA84FB8032AC8EE66C171307AAC3AB4975E8F4E9A3172EEBF70CC22C2FBEE59,
iv =33AF2CC39DBD524AA7BB2B393F882D65, did u use my code?

Comment: Fine, match those on my machine. What does the C# code provide for key and IV?

Comment: Key: 0EA4723A0CBA5B2BC6004A1A519CA9D20CAAE19131E4E0FB7D21B46736BD4933,
IV: 1CD9D3EC1F9CBD74CB4A24C84C4EA1CA

Comment: Different. This is the C# code I run with your _unmodified_ function: `var passphrase = File.ReadAllBytes(@"<path to secret.key>"); var ciphertext = File.ReadAllBytes(@"<path to encrypted_file>"); Console.WriteLine(DecryptAesCbc(ciphertext, passphrase));` Maybe try this.

Comment: Oh my god it works! Now is the question why it didn't work with the original data

Comment: You received a different key and IV with your code during the test. This will likely be the cause.

Comment: Okay i reverted a lot of the code, and it now even works with the rsa encyption on the secret. So it may have been a bad secret after all?

Comment: Maybe, but hard to say.

Comment: Okay now i know. I have recreated a secret with 192 bytes and it stopped working. So it seems that a 192 byte secret is too big or such?

Comment: This is especially possible with respect to RSA encryption, because RSA can only encrypt small messages (smaller than the RSA key size).

Comment: Sadly that isn't the problem. I have tried a 192 byte secret without RSA and it didn't work either

Comment: Nevertheless, how long is the RSA key?

Comment: The RSA key is 4096 bytes

Comment: OK, then you can't encrypt quite 512 bytes.

Comment: I have never used such a long password before. Actually, `rand` generates a key. Why do you apply a key as password and why such a long password? Maybe openssl has a problem with such long passwords (but this is just a wild guess), best check the docs.

Comment: Openssl itself has no problem decrypting. The encryption with RSA is done with a certificate (which is 4096 bytes) as it is used for other occasions as well. The RSA encryption is used to encrypt the secret.key as it is stored alongside the license file. And to decrypt the license you need the rsa private key to decrypt the secret, with which you can decrypt the license.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the long password is the problem (the short one works). Two possible explanations are, RSA (limited message size) or the parsing of such a long key by openssl. You seem to have ruled out RSA, so that leaves parsing. You can evaluate this with further tests.

Comment: The problem isn't in RSA and also not in OpenSSL as the decryption works with OpenSSL, but the C# implementation RFC2898DeriveBytes can't seem to handle a passphrase that is longer than 128 bytes. Atleast in my case.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why. `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` works on my machine (.NET Core 3.1+ and .NET Framework 4.8) even with a 384 byte passphrase.

Comment: For information on where the salt is stored, and how the key and iv are derived from the password when using `openssl aes-256-cbc -e -pbkdf2`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761458/how-to-decrypt-openssl-aes-encrypted-files-in-python.

Comment: For binary data, the following explanation would be plausible: If a random password is generated with `openssl-rand`, one or more line breaks may also be randomly generated. openssl determines the password only up to the first line break (s. `openssl-enc` doc). Decryption with the C# code would fail, because the C# code takes the whole password into account. This could explain your problems pretty well.

Comment: Therefore a binary-to-text-encoding must be applied (e.g. Base64 or hex). Since openssl doesn't perform any decoding when loading the password, no decoding must be performed in the C# code under any circumstances either. Basically, the bug is due to a conceptual issue and arises because a key is used as a password, which, unlike a password, consists of arbitrary binary data.

Comment: Oh thank you very much! This was it. I now generate the secret with ```openssl rand 192 | openssl enc -A -base64 -out secret.key``` and it works flawlessly even with 192 bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
public static string DecryptLicense(byte[] cipherData, byte[] passphrase)
{
  string decrypted = null;
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream(cipherData))
  {
    // Get salt
    var salt = new byte[8];
    ms.Seek(8, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    ms.Read(salt, 0, 8);

    // Derive key and IV
    var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passphrase, salt, 10000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    byte[] key = pbkdf2.GetBytes(32);
    byte[] iv = pbkdf2.GetBytes(16);

    using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aes.Key = key;
    aes.IV = iv;

    // Decrypt
    ICryptoTransform decipher = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
    using var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decipher, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    using var sr = new StreamReader(cs, Encoding.UTF8);
    decrypted = sr.ReadToEnd();
  }

  return decrypted;
}
```

and generate the passphrase with: `openssl rand 192 | openssl enc -A -base64 -out secret.key`

The problem was a passphrase which was generated with newlines and openssl uses just the first line from a passphrase file, but C# uses the whole file to derive the keys. In order to prevent that, i now generate a file with no linebreaks.